# Как в Django посчитать количество дочерних объектов с условием?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Кто может сталкивался и знает способ?
в общем, допустим имеются модели:

```
class catalog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название')

class book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название')
    sold = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Продана?')
    type = models.ForeignKey(catalog, blank=True, null=True, related_name='type_cat', verbose_name='Каталог', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Нужно вывести в HTML количество тех, которые не проданы. Как вывести все, понятно, так:

```
{{ catalog.type_cat.all|length }}
```

или так:

```
{{ catalog.type_cat.count }}
```

есть ли решение отфильтровать на уровне шаблона? Или это надо функции в модели или вьюхе писать?

Comment: В шаблоне должна быть только простая презентационная логика, к которой фильтрация данных не относится.

Answer (score 1):

views.py:

```py
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .models import book #Кстати классы лучше называть с большой буквы

class BookListView(ListView):
    model = book
    template_name = 'books/your-template.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Получаем контекст из родительского класса ListView
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Дополняем контекст нужным нам значением
        context['not_sold_books_count'] = book.objects.filter(sold=False).count()

        return context
```

Теперь при рендере шаблона `books/your-template.html` в нем появится нужная вам переменная. Использовать ее можно как обычно - `{{not_sold_books_count}}`

Comment: Я решил этот вопрос добавлением функции в модель. Не знаю на сколько это правильно, пример кода в сообщении ниже.

Answer (score 0):

Как альтернативный вариант, вы можете написать [фильтр для шаблона django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/), который будет фильтровать значения. В итоге можно отфильтровать примерно так

```
  {{ catalog.type_cat.all|filter_qs:'sold:bool:False'|length }}
```

В фильтре шаблона делим переданную строку по `:`, первый элемент - название поля, второй - тип значения, которое передаем, третий - само значение. Преобразуем значение в указанный тип.

Для bool можно сравнить `value = value == 'True'`, а еще лучше проверять, что значение либо True, либо False, в противном случае выкидывать исключение. Например так

```
if value in ['True', 'False']:
    value = value == 'True'
else:
    raise ValueError('Я не знаю, что вы передали. Я хочу bool')
```

Для целых/вещественных можно преобразовать через `int()` или `float()` соответсвенно, обрабатывая исключения

Как только преобразуете данные, сможете отфильтровать QuerySet

```
res_qs = qs.filter(**{field_name: value})
```

Но нужно учитывать, что это поле есть в модели, объекты которой фильтруем.

---

PS: Не лучший вариант для разработки. Лучше фильтровать и передавать в контексте, но если ОЧЕНЬ хочется в шаблоне, то этот вариант для ленивых подойдет. Но в будущем скорее всего вы будете страдать из-за того, что не сможете найти место, в котором делали фильтрацию, ибо по стандартам разработки на Django в шаблон нужно пережавать уже готовые данные, а в самом шаблоне - управлять выводом на основе уже подготовленных данных

Answer (score 0):

Я решил данный вопрос добавлением функции в модели:

```
class catalog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название')

    def not_sold(self):
        not_sold_book = len(self.type_cat.all().filter(sold=False))
        return not_sold_book

class book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название')
    sold = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Продана?')
    type = models.ForeignKey(catalog, blank=True, null=True, related_name='type_cat', verbose_name='Каталог', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

И в шаблоне просто использую значение функции:
{{ catalog.not_sold_book }}

Честно говоря я в python и Django новичок, по этому буду признателен, если кто подскажет, какой вариант правильнее.

Comment: Лучше `not_sold_book = self.type_cat.filter(sold=False).count()`. И да, выносить обработку данных за пределы шаблонов - хорошая практика.

Comment: Так какой ответ отмечать верным?

Comment: Дополни свой ответ ответами других участников, и отметь его.